# how to use Merge in kerase>2.0?

Tags: keras, word2vec, keras-layer, keras-2

```
word_model=Sequential() word_model.add(Embedding(vocab_size,embed_size,               embeddings_initializer="glorot_uniform",               input_length=1)) word_model.add(Reshape((embed_size,)))

context_model=Sequential() context_model.add(Embedding(vocab_size,embed_size,               embeddings_initializer="glorot_uniform",               input_length=1)) context_model.add(Reshape((embed_size,)))

model=Sequential()model.add(Merge([word_model,context_model],mode="dot")) model.add(Dense(1,init="glorot_unifor",activation="sigmod")) model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",optimizer="adam")
```

how to change those in keras2, which has no merge methods any more

Comment: Probably this is something you are looking for?: https://keras.io/layers/merge/#dot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Merge` API has been changed. The new API is documented [here](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#dot).

In your example, instead of doing this:
`Merge([word_model,context_model],mode="dot")`

Do this:
`keras.layers.dot([word_model,context_model])`

and it should work!